# Error using DjangoFramework in template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, frameworks

new try of dev here.

Im trying to make a project and I alredy having some issues that i dont know why dont work... I put my code and explain it...

url.py

```
app_name = 'opotest'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.indexView, name='index'),
    url(r'^inicio/$', views.ListaView.as_view(), name='inicio'),
    url(r'^test/(?P<tipo>.+)/$', views.TestList.as_view(), name='test'),    
    url(r'^test/(?P<tipo>.+)/run/$',
        views.TestDetail.as_view(), name='run'),  # this one
```

View.py

```
class TestDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pregunta.objects.all()
```

HTML template

```
{% for test in lista  %}

    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ pregunta.textopregunta }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Models.py

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    textopregunta = models.CharField('Texto pregunta', max_length=1000)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.textopregunta
```

This code should bring me some 'pregunta' that i have alredy created but it doesnt work... can you please tell me what im doing wrong? the for bring me

Pregunta:

the textopregunta do not appears...

Thanks everyone

D...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
{% for test in lista  %}

    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ test.textopregunta }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

will work,

but anyway, if you want to use `Pregunta.objects.all()` , you must use `ListView`, not `DetailView`. Like this

```
class TestList(generic.ListView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'

{% for test in lista  %}

    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ test.textopregunta }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

#### UPDATE

If you want to list all your model objects, please use `ListView`.

#### 1. Change your view to `ListView`

```
class TestList(generic.ListView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'
```

Then you can use `objects` and `lista` both in tempalte.

#### 2. Change your url

You don't need `tipo` in url, if it's listview.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.indexView, name='index'),
    url(r'^inicio/$', views.ListaView.as_view(), name='inicio'),
    url(r'^test/(?P<tipo>.+)/$', views.TestList.as_view(), name='test'),    
    url(r'^test/run/$',
        views.TestList.as_view(), name='run'),  # this one
```

#### 3. use `objects` or `lista` in templates.

Because you define `lista` in `context_object_name` : it means your objects list will be used with `lista` in template. (you can use `objects` cause django `ListView` automatically make context for you)

```
{% for test in lista  %}

    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ test.textopregunta }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

#### UPDATE for DetailView

#### 1. Change urls with pk

Above all, you have to understand about `View` - `Template` and `urls`.

In your urls - you should pass params what you want to use to grep your one specific object. It should be unique, so just use `pk`(id). (Or you can make your own unique slug)

```
    url(r'^test/run/$',
        views.TestList.as_view(), name='run'),  # this one  
    # this is DetailView
    url(r'^test/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        views.TestDetail.as_view(), name='run'),  # this one
```

Then your url will be.. `test/1/` , `test/2/`.

#### 2. change views

Actually, django CBV supports many functions (method) so you don't have to handle more but it's hard to understand.

```
class TestDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'
```

You're confusing when you don't know about `DetailView`.

In `DetailView`, (as you can see [here-ccbv.co.kr](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) ) it has `get_object()` method. If any `url_kwargs` defined in your view, it use `pk` for basic. So it will find like `Pregunta.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get(pk))` that takes from your `urls.py`.

Then you can use your object in template, using `lista` or `object`.

```
    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ lista.textopregunta }}</p>
```

You DONT have to forloop all objects (actually CANT) because `DetailView` basically find your object from your `kwargs` (in this situation, `pk`).

I highly recommend reading django docs (CBV) and seeing [ccbv.co.kr](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) for understanding CBV, or trying to use FBV in django.

Comment: it is not working... i thought that it was okay too... but i dont know why dont work, how can i use a return for 1 'pregunta' using filter ()[1]

Comment: You want all `pregunta` objects? or only one object for detailview?

Comment: I think you have lots of probelm - i.e. url : what's `tipo`? why you don't use `pk` or `slug` ?

Comment: i just want one ... but i dont know how to chose just one... still learning.

Comment: Oh I just update that shows all.. If you want one, it will be changed for `DetailView` with `pk` or something in your urls. I will update answer again.

Comment: but i need detail view to watch the content of pregunta and make a decission of vote any option that i will dsign later

Comment: url(r'^test/run/$', views.TestDetail.as_view(), name='run'),    
..
Reverse for 'run' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['test/run/$']

Comment: I updated answer. And your error above it's because of your urls. You shoulw remove the line `url(r'^test/(?P<tipo>.+)/$', views.TestList.as_view(), name='test'),` cause it's duplicated for listview - and be aware making urls : it also be long answer...

Comment: 1. if you hit url, it will find from high to low.
2. You hit url with `/test/run/` 
3. Then it tracked with `test/(?P<tipo>.+)/` => cause regex `.+` means EVERY word ( DO NOT use that)
It's why you have to be aware of url order.

Comment: Thanks it works... you made it ! thanks you man, have a nice day.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you. Anyway, you should try django official tutorial, or django girl's tutorial - they are all good for beginners

Answer (score 1):

try to override the `get_context_data()` method, as below then change your template also,

```
class TestDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pregunta.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['sample'] = self.get_queryset()
        return context
```

Try to change your template as below,

```
{% for test in sample  %}

    <br/>
    <p>Pregunta: {{ test.textopregunta }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i´ve tried and it dindt work :l :(((( still no displaying 'textopregunta'

Comment: no... its so weird! the for works it give me 2  <p>Pregunta: </p> but the textopregunta no...

Comment: maybe could be my return at detail view? how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

By default Generic.DetailView looks for `pk` in the url parameters which is used to search data from your database. In your case you are using `tipo` as url parameters. So, you need to override the default inside your view. Your code should be something like this:

```
class TestDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    context_object_name = 'lista'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'tipo'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pregunta.objects.all()
```

Now it will 
look for `tipo` in your url and take the parameters to search from your database. More on Generic views can be found on this link: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/